# Parsing arxml file with python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a file I need to parse, I need the information. The order of parsing is important.

1. I can parse the file and get the information, but not in the sequence.
2. How can I parse the information `<MSR-QUERY-ARG SI="HtmlAnchor">`?

Btw: Where can I upload the arxml file?

File-Download: [ARXML-FILE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18VJXpZR8-uEtVAHZoPA37Pc1rQHqLzbE)

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import csv

fpath = "test.arxml"

tree = ET.parse(fpath)
root = tree.getroot()

ns = {'ns':'http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0'}

for arpackage in tree.findall('.//ns:CHAPTER/ns:TRACE',namespaces=ns):
    print(arpackage.findall('.//ns:SHORT-NAME', namespaces=ns)[0].text)

for arpackage in tree.findall('.//ns:CHAPTER/ns:MSR-QUERY-P-1', namespaces=ns):
    print(arpackage.findall('.//ns:MSR-QUERY-ARG', namespaces=ns)[0].text)
```

Comment: Re: "where can I upload the file", you don't: you should paste a subset of it into your question, sufficient to clarify the question you're asking.

Comment: I mean with sequence. I need the data in the same order as in the file. for example: S_001, S_002, A_001, S_003, A_002.
With separate for-loops I get: S_001, S_002, S_003, A_001, A_002 (false sequence)
With two nested for-loops I get the data multiple times and in false order.
I hope I was able to describe my problem.

Comment: Still unclear. In the XML file, `A_001` does not appear between `S_002` and `S_003`. `S_002` is on line 106, `S_003` is on line 116 and `A_001` is on line 585.

Comment: It was just an example, but the A-values appear between S-values.

Comment: It was just an example, but the A-values appear between S-values.
In this case I need the output like S_034, S_035, AAA_001, AAA_002, S_036, S_037, AAA_003, S_038 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
html = utils.getFileContent('test.arxml')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
names = doc.selects('TRACE').selects('SHORT-NAME>text()')
msrs = doc.selects('MSR-QUERY-P-1').select('MSR-QUERY-ARG@SI="HtmlAnchor">text()')
print (names)
print (msrs)
```

Result:

```
[['S_001'], ['S_002'], ['S_003'], ['S_004'], ['S_005'], ['S_006'], ['S_007'], ['S_008'], ['S_009'], ['S_010'], ['S_011'], ['S_012'], ['S_013'], ['S_014'], ['S_015'], ['S_016'], ['S_017'], ['S_018'], ['S_019'], ['S_020'], ['S_021'], ['S_022'], ['S_023'], ['S_024'], ['S_025'], ['S_026'], ['S_027'], ['S_028'], ['S_029'], ['S_030'], ['S_031'], ['S_032'], ['S_033'], ['S_034'], ['S_035'], ['S_036'], ['S_037'], ['S_038'], ['S_039']]
['AAA_001', 'AAA_002', 'AAA_003']
```

Here are more examples, including parsing and updating:  https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples